# Reuse output from command 1 in command 2 using a pipe

Tags: linux, pipe, cat

I've got a command in linux which returns a list of numbers. Now I need this numbers to form a directory path and cat the file located at that path.
For example:
myCommand returns:

```
1 
10
30 
40
```

And I want to cat all the files that look like this:

```
 /folder/1/folder2 
 /folder/10/folder2 
 /folder/30/folder2
 /folder/40/folder2
```

I Hope it is clear what I want, if not, feel free to ask.
This is my code right now:

```
 myCommand | xargs cat
```

But it obviously doesn't work since directory 1,10,30 and 40 doesn't exist.

**I want the output to be: the catted value - number generated by myCommand**

Comment: `myCommand | xargs -I{} cat /folder/{}/folder2/*` but much better use loop `for` or/and `find`

Comment: How would you do that with a for-loop?

Comment: `for genpath in $(myCommand); do cat /folder/$genpath/folder2/* ; echo $genpath ; done`

Comment: Thank you, by doing it with a forloop I could also display the value of I, which I wanted! If you write it as an answer I will mark it as the solution to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to do thing with `xargs`

```
myCommand | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo -n {}\ ; cat /folder/{}/folder2/file'
```

But more syntaxically right and much flexible do it with `for` loop:

```
for genpath in $(myCommand)
do
    echo -n $genpath\ 
    cat /folder/$genpath/folder2/file
done
```

Or even through `while` loop

```
while read genpath
do
    echo -n $genpath\ 
    cat /folder/$genpath/folder2/file
done < <(myCommand)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-I` with `xargs` to replace a placeholder in your command:

```
myCommand | xargs -I % cat /folder/%/folder2
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I show the output as " the catted value - number generated by myCommand " ?

Comment: You want the "myCommand" number appended to each line of the cat'ed files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use command substitution with bracket list expansion:

```
cat /folder/["$(myCommand)"]/folder2
```

---

Example with `printf` as a command:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3
$ echo a > dir1/file
$ echo b > dir2/file
$ echo c > dir3/file
$ cat ./dir["$(printf "%s\n" {1..3})"]/file
a
b
c
```

Comment: (1) Can you please explain *how* this works? (1a) I have trouble getting it to work when I leave off the `./`. Why would that be significant? (2) Can you get this to work for numbers that are not single digits; e.g., `10`, `30`, and `40`, as mentioned in the question?